# Динамическое добавление/получение значений из массива

Tags: php

У меня есть есть строка(паттерн):

```
$pattern = 'config.images.0.width';
```

Мне нужно динамически на основе этого паттерна построить массив, чтобы получилось следующие:

```
$arr['config']['images'][0]['width'] = 500;
$width = $arr['config']['images'][0]['width'];
```

Как видно, "руками" - это сделать не проблема но как это сделать динамически?

Comment: https://github.com/artoodetoo/container/blob/master/src/Container.php#L121 https://github.com/artoodetoo/container/blob/master/src/Container.php#L98

Comment: Спасибо, но не подходит. Там объект, а мне нужно добавлять в массив

Comment: Там нет объекта. `$this->config` является массивом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pattern = 'config.images.0.width';
$value = 400;
$keys = explode('.', $pattern);
$arr=[];
function addInner($keys, &$arr, $value){
    $key = array_shift($keys);
    $arr[$key] = null;
    if(empty($keys)) {
        $arr[$key] = $value;
        return;
    }
    addInner($keys, $arr[$key], $value);
}

addInner($keys, $arr, $value);
```

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dd3b394fc7ff818ce733b04c01398908d4291534)

Answer (score 1):

Довольно простой и короткий вариант:

```
function getValueByPath($path, $array) {
    $tmp = &$array;

    foreach($path as $key) {
        $tmp =& $tmp[$key];
    }
    return $tmp;
}



//-----------------------------------------
// Пример использования
// 
// Входные данные
$arr = ['f1' => 1,
        'config' => [
            'videos' => 'http://video.ru',
            'images' => [
                ['width' => 100, 'height' => 80 ], 
                ['width' => 666, 'height' => 1 ], 
                ['width' => 0, 'height' => 0 ], 
            ]
        ],
        'f3' => null
];        

// путь
$key = 'config.images.0.width';
$path = explode('.', $key);

// output
$result = getValueByPath($path, $arr); 
echo $result;  // 100
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bd93fccc8070b46ec246e2aa460ddadc1bd117e1

Подсмотрено на https://stackoverflow.com/a/27930028/6104996

---

Смысл в том, что при каждом проходе цикла в `tmp` складывается значение по ключу из предыдущей итерации. На начальной итерации `tmp` соответствует первоначальному массиву.

- 0 шаг (до цикла):

  ```
  $tmp = ['f1' => 1,
          'config' => [
              'videos' => 'http://video.ru',
              'images' => [
                  ['width' => 100, 'height' => 80 ], 
                  ['width' => 666, 'height' => 1 ], 
                  ['width' => 0, 'height' => 0 ], 
              ]
          ],
          'f3' => null
  ];
  ```
- 1 итерация (`$tmp['config']`)

  ```
  $tmp = ['videos' => 'http://video.ru',
          'images' => [
              ['width' => 100, 'height' => 80 ], 
              ['width' => 666, 'height' => 1 ], 
              ['width' => 0, 'height' => 0 ], 
          ]
  ];
  ```
- 2 итерация (`$tmp['images']`)

  ```
  $tmp = [
          ['width' => 100, 'height' => 80 ], 
          ['width' => 666, 'height' => 1 ], 
          ['width' => 0, 'height' => 0 ],                 
  ];
  ```
- 3 итерация (`$tmp[0]`)

  ```
  $tmp = ['width' => 100, 'height' => 80 ];
  ```
- 4 итерация (`$tmp['width']`)

  ```
  $tmp = 100;
  ```