# Как вывести в консоль значение объекта по строке

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
let obj = {
  summaryNinety:{
    children:{
      medianUnitCost:{
        errors:'errors'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Нужно как то так

```
console.log(obj['summaryNinety.children.medianUnitCost']);
```

Но сработает как то так

```
console.log(obj['summaryNinety']['children']['medianUnitCost']);
```

Подскажите как по строке добраться до свойства

Если сделать так получится массив

```
let id = 'summaryNinety.children.medianUnitCost';
let arr = id.split('.');
```

Но как его подставить?

Comment: написать функцию, которая распарсит строку и приведет её как раз к виду `obj['summaryNinety']['children']['medianUnitCost']` ..... вот вариант с PHP https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/686178/191482

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не соображу как чего то=)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тянуть по одному в рекурсии?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский походу в рекурсии все же думал есть какой то оператор

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
function getObjectData( object, path ){
    let dataParams = path.split('.');

    if( ! dataParams.length ){
        return object;
    }

    let ret = object[dataParams[0]];
    for( let i = 1; i < dataParams.length; i++ ){
        ret = ret[dataParams[i]];
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Соответственно вывод в консоль следующий: `console.log( getObjectData( obj, 'summaryNinety.children.medianUnitCost' ) );`

Comment: let data = obj;
for(let key in arr){
 data = data[arr[key]];
}

Comment: Проверку надо сделать. Если где-то в середине не будет такого ключа - ошибка выстрелит.

Comment: блин жаль что нет другого способа, проверку сделаю, спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот так

```js
let obj = {
  summaryNinety:{
    children:{
      medianUnitCost:{
        errors:'errors'
      }
    }
  }
};

console.log('summaryNinety.children.medianUnitCost.errors'.split('.').reduce((a,v)=>{
  if(a === null){
    return obj[v];
  }
  return a[v];
}, null));
```