# Как получить элемент многомерного массива, из функции, передав её ключ в качестве аргумента?

Tags: php, массивы, функции

**Пример:**

```
<?php

$_POST = array(
    'a' => 'apple',
    'b' => 'banana',
    'c' => array(
        'd' => 'data'
    )
);

function test($key) {
    return $_POST[$key];
}

echo test('a'); //Получим Apple
```

**Вопрос:**

Как таким же образом получить элемент "data". Либо любой другой элемент, на несколько уровней глубже.

Comment: А какой `$key` вы хотите передать, чтобы получить значение `data`?

Comment: Ну стандартно это будет так $_POST['c']['d'], а в функцию например массив этих ключей в качестве аргумента, но как их там подставить?

Comment: Нашел дубликат, можно закрывать)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $_POST = array(
        'a' => 'apple',
        'b' => 'banana',
        'c' => array(
            'd' => 'data'
        )
    );

    function test($key) {
        return $_POST[$key];
    }
    $test = test('c');
    echo $test['d'];
```

вот так вы имели ввиду?

```
<?php

$_POST = array(
    'a' => 'apple',
    'b' => 'banana',
    'c' => array(
        'd' => 'data'
    )
);

function test($key) {
    if(is_array($key))
    {
        return $key['d'];
    }
    return $_POST[$key];
}
$test = test($_POST['c']);
echo $test;
```

Comment: Как вариант, а нет возможности сделать то же, но в качестве аргумента передать массив с ключами?

Comment: не пойму что вы хотите

Comment: Ну например: test('b'); //banana, нельзя ли переделать функцию так чтобы например передать массив ключей получить 'data', например: test(array('c', 'd')); //data. Надеюсь объяснил)

Comment: тогда в функции test($key) надо разбирать массив,если пришел массив

Comment: Понимаю, но как соорудить потом: $_POST['c']['d'] // Внутри самой функции...

Comment: Если знаете как дайте пример, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Посмотрите второй вариант. Надеюсь я  вас правильно понял

Comment: Не совсем как раз таки и нужно избавится от $_POST, то есть чтобы он был только внутри функции, а передавать только ключи, питаюсь разобраться в этом:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/686178/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0#703751 Похоже мой вариант

Comment: Спасибо за старания, отмечу как дубликат.